# Deduce template argument when lambda passed in as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am trying to write function `func` so that compiler can deduce template argument, it works when I pass in `std::function`, but does not work with lambdas:

```
template<typename TResult>
TResult func(std::function<TResult()> f)
{
    return TResult();
}

int main()
{
                                // Visual Studio 2013
    int result = func([]() {    // error: 'TResult func(std::function<TResult(void)>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::function<TResult(void)>' from 'main::<lambda_d9d7854806072a2cb711f56185602ccb>'
        return 100;
    });

    std::function<int()> testFunc = []() {
        return 100;
    };
    int result2 = func(testFunc); // this works

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to deduce template argument for lambda so that this line compiles? Instead of writing `func<int>([](){ return 100; });` I want to write `func([](){ return 100; });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see how to do it immediately but you can do it with in an indirection:

```
template <typename TResult>
TResult func(std::function<TResult()> f) {
    return TResult();
}

template <typename Fun>
auto func(Fun f) -> decltype(f()) {
    return func(std::function<decltype(f())>(f));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm late a little bit :)
There is a solution without `std::function`

```
template<typename Class, typename R, typename... Args>
R resultType(R (Class::*)(Args...) const)
{
    return R();
}

template<typename Class, typename R, typename... Args>
R resultType(R (Class::*)(Args...))
{
    return R();
}

template<typename Functor>
auto func(Functor f) -> decltype(resultType(&Functor::operator()))
{
    return resultType(&Functor::operator());
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution! But shouldn't you overload `resultType()` for `noexcept` in the same manner as for `const`?

Answer (score 2):

At least if I understand the intent, I believe you can do things this way:

```
template <class F>
auto foo(F &&f) -> decltype(f()) {
    typedef decltype(f()) ret_type;
    return ret_type();
}
```

...or if you prefer to do without the `typedef`:

```
template <class F>
auto foo(F &&f) -> decltype(f()) {
    return decltype(f())();
}
```

Complete program, comparing usage and results:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <class F>
auto foo(F &&f) -> decltype(f()) {
    return decltype(f())();
}

template<typename TResult>
TResult func(std::function<TResult()> f) {
    return TResult();
}

int main() {
   std::cout << foo([]() { return 100; })<<"\n";

    std::function<int()> testFunc=[]() { return 100; };
    std::cout << func(testFunc) <<"\n"; // this works

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
0
0
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't use `std::function` here, the compiler can't deduce its type arguments.

You should just pass the parameter as `TFunction`.